# Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0 when launching rails 3.0.5 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I installed the gem SystemTimer 1.2.3 but still getting this error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Getting the same error after upgrading to 3.0.6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I added the following to my Gemfile and the error went away.

```
gem 'SystemTimer', '1.2.3'
```

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. I am not sure why I need it now all of a sudden but glad it is resolved.